# Comma placement: "Hi, my name is Joe and I work in a button factory."

Tags: punctuation, commas

Will someone please tell me where commas should go in the following sentence:

> Hi, my name is Joe and I work in a button factory.

Comment: Maybe I'm less liberal with commas than others, but I think you have all the commas you need in that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
Hi, my name is Joe, and I work in a button factory!
```

You're missing the all-important exclamation point at the end, of course.

"my name is Joe" can be completely removed from the sentence and it still makes sense. It's either a subordinating or independent clause, depending on how much you've been drinking, therefore you can surround the clause with commas to show its relative unimportance.

Comment: Can you really remove that portion of the sentence? "Hi and I work in a button factory" isn't right, unless you're referring to someone else whose name is Hi. I don't think _my name is Joe_ is a clause in this sentence.

Comment: @Andy: The ", and" is a compound conjunction, so you would be removing all of that. "Hi I work in a button factory" is the independent phrase of the sentence. My name is Joe is certainly a separate clause, although it definitely is more courteous and socially acceptable to include it in an introduction.

Comment: @Jordan: maybe I was being a tad pedantic.

Answer (score 6):

**There are several possible options**, which will give slightly different meaning and emphasis.  (Punctuation often has this effect, just like stress and intonation do in speech.)  The two most natural are probably:

> Hi, my name is Joe, and I work in a button factory.

> Hi, my name is Joe and I work in a button factory.

The former of these breaks up the statement more, so stresses the sequentiality of the parts: first you’re giving your name, then where you work.  The second puts the two clauses on a more equal footing: you’re giving two statements about yourself at the same time.

It would be much less likely, but one could imagine situations where a third option would work:

> Hi, my name is Joe, and I work, in a button factory.

This version separates out “I work” as an independent assertion, with the location “in a button factory” then elaborating on it.  One wouldn’t normally want to do this — usually, the significant information is *where* I work, not just the fact that I do — but it could make sense in response to something like “Hello, my name’s Mary, and I’m currently unemployed.”

Aside: Punctuation is amazingly powerful, almost as much as tone of voice!  If we start changing other aspects of the punctuation, we can get lots more meanings out of the same words:

> Hi!  My name is Joe!  And I work in a button factory!

> Hi, my name is Joe, and I work in… a *button* factory?

etc, etc.

Comment: To continue your alternative punctuation.    Hi, my name is Joe and I "work" in a button factory.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, a comma before the *and* is optional and helps express a slightly different meaning. But it should be noted that the first comma, after the *Hi* is required to separate *Hi* as an interjection. So *Hi, my name is Joe..* is correct, but *Hi my name is Joe...* is not.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is two complete sentences joined  with a conjunction. If it is punctuated properly, it is considered a compound sentence. A comma is necessary before the “and”.  Otherwise, without the comma, the sentence is a run-on sentence.

Comment: Hello, Laura. No; commas after coordinators are not mandatory per se. This is an over-prescriptive rule (really it should be regarded as a rule of thumb) sadly still to be found in older textbooks and the like. See **ect**'s answer (which cites a very good 2002 article by Tina Blue, a Lecturer Emeritus at Kansas University, I believe, gracing  'Grammartips')  at [A comma before 'and' in compound sentences – necessary or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences-necessary-or-not)