# coordinating conjunction and (with comma)...?

Tags: punctuation, commas, coordinating-conjunctions

coordinating conjunctions?

Do I have to put the comma before "and" here?

a) In 2007, I moved to New York, and Peter moved to Berlin.

b) I created a code, and in each of them are numbers.

c) Yesterday, Peter drank beer,and Joe ate a bread.

D) 5+2 equals 7, and 7+3 equals 10.

THANK YOU! :)

Comment: Duplicate of [comma before 'and'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and).

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes; two independent clauses ("SVO") are connected by a comma and a coordinating conjunction (and, but, or, so, for). But if the two sentences are short, as in your examples, the comma can be omitted for stylistic reasons (i.e. to prevent the reader/speaker from always pausing).

Source (one of many): http://theeditorsblog.net/2011/02/26/no-comma-necessary-coordinating-conjunctions-dont-always-need-commas/

Comment: But in d) for instance, there's the adverb "Yesterday" and the following statements depend on it to be true right? Because it was yesterday when Peter drank a beer and it was yesterday when Joe ate a bread. Does this mean, in this case, I even HAVE TO ommit the comma? Since I can't split them into two sentences due to "Yesterday"?  Thank you ;)

Comment: I think context would be sufficient for readers to know that both occurred yesterday. If Joe ate bread at another time, you would usually point that out ("and Joe ate bread today."). Also, bread is uncountable.

Comment: Sorry; 'technically' is a weasel-word hereabouts. 'According to authorities A and B, ...' (including links) shows the standard of answer expected on ELU.

Comment: Got it and updated.