# Can a comma before a coordinating conjunction be parenthetical?

Tags: punctuation, commas, parentheticals, coordinating-conjunctions

#### Can an ostensibly misused comma before a coordinating conjunction actually be a parenthetical comma?

Consider:

> Sally picked apples, and placed them in her basket.

This is considered a misuse of the comma, as the second clause is dependent. It should be

> Sally picked apples and placed them in her basket.

or converted into "Sally picked apples, and she placed them in her basket" (the second clause is now independent).

Now consider:

> Sally picked apples (and placed them in her basket).

Here the second clause as a parenthetical one, right? So surely you could write, equivalently:

> Sally picked apples, and placed them in her basket.

where obviously, you omit replacing the closing bracket with a comma as it's the end of the sentence. What gives?

---

P.S. I have a feeling that either of

> Sally picked apples (placing them in her basket).
>
> Sally picked apples, placing them in her basket.

is a more accurate use of parenthesis, without knowing why.

Comment: I don't think you are using parentheses correctly. An example usage would be **Sally picked apples (some were unripe) and placed them in her basket**.

Comment: In "Sally [picked apples], and [placed them in her basket]", there is no dependent clause, but a coordination of two verb phrases, as bracketed. But I agree that a comma is not required.

Comment: Essentially answered at [Comma before "and"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and). Whether one's definition of 'parenthetical' encompasses 'and + subject-deleted independent clause' is not really relevant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your link leads to a first class answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Uh, actually whether the definition of parenthesis encompasses etc. is precisely what I'm targeting. I would like an answer that says either "No, 'and placed them in her basket' is not a valid parenthesis for X reason", or whatever is correct in this situation

Comment: A compound predicate is not usually treated as a parenthetical, though your << Sally picked apples (and placed them in her basket). >> is obviously an example of a sentence containing a parenthetical and  modelled on a compound predicate construction. And using a comma instead of two brackets is normally an acceptable alternative for offsetting. See [this article](https://www.englishforums.com/English/CommaCompoundPredicateParenthetical-Phrase/gqdrg/post.htm) at EnglishForums for further discussion. // The ...

Comment: bottom line is that the comma is unnecessary, though there are a growing number of writers who consider it perfectly acceptable to use commas 'merely' to signal a pause, where loss of clarity does not ensue. The reason for using the comma would be to separate the consideration of the two actions: to give a feel of some time between them, and/or to add emphasis. This is one of the pragmatic functions of less contentious parenthesising anyway, so terminology is not really a problem.

Comment: I would use an Em dash to indicate a pause.