# Why isn't there a comma put here? explain to me please

Tags: commas

I usually 100% of the time put a comma here. Since there is the conjunction being "but" and a subject straight after being "they" meaning that it's essential to put a comma, however, I've been told a comma is not necessary here. I think they are wrong but Grammarly also doesn't add this. Can anybody explain this?

"Boeing is known for airplanes(,) but they actually have a long history in space."

Comment: The use of commas is often a matter of style. There's nothing wrong with omitting the comma here but that might conflict with the requirements of your Style Manual (if one applies to you).

Comment: I understand commas can be used for style, but they also have mandatory uses in some scenarios. this is not a style manual scenario. I just don't understand why this is omittable in this circumstance. Since it goes against my teaching. If I'm wrong I want to know why so I can fix it

Comment: You can *choose* to omit it because there's no "rule". Some people teach that you must always put a comma before *but*, but others will tell you that you don't have to.  *There is no universal rule.* Does the sentence make sense (and the meaning isn't altered) without the comma? If yes, then it's optional. Does your teacher / institution / publisher require you to follow a style guide or instruction that mandates a comma before *but*? If yes, it's *not* optional. I can't be any more help than that.

Comment: Could you add a reference for the teaching you're talking about?  I've never heard of an English rule that makes a comma "mandatory" at any time.  To my knowledge a comma may be desirable or undesirable, helpful or confusing, but there are no set rules.

Comment: Not sure if I'm allowed to link here, however, my past college experience and recently an Academic English: Writing Course I completed on Coursera from the University of California, Irvine. Stressed the importance of mandatory commas in certain areas. And the course would not let you continue other parts of the course if your use of mandatory comma scenarios was insufficient. You can try it for 7 days free on the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma before "and"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and) (which also covers but and other conjunctions) (see ect's answer).

Comment: The first comment is not true, there are rules for commas. It's not a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of style. If *you* always use a comma, then it's probably easier for you to continue to do so for the sake of consistency.

But, for instance, *The Chicago Manual of Style*, 6.22, says this:

> When independent clauses are joined by *and, but, or, so, yet*, or any other coordinating conjunction, a comma usually precedes the conjunction. If the clauses are very short and closely connected, the comma may be omitted (as in the last two examples) unless the clauses are part of a series. These recommendations apply equally to imperative sentences, in which the subject (you) is omitted but understood (as in the fifth and last examples).
>
> We activated the alarm, but the intruder was already inside.
>       All watches display the time, and some of them do so accurately.
>       Do we want to foster creativity, or are we interested only in our intellectual property?
>       The bus never came, so we took a taxi.
>       Wait for me at the bottom of the hill on Buffalo Street, or walk up to Eddy Street and meet me next to the Yield sign.
>       Donald cooked, Sally poured the wine, and Maddie and Cammie offered hors d’oeuvres.
>
> *but*
>
> Electra played the guitar and Tambora sang.
>       Raise your right hand and repeat after me.

Not only does *CMOS* point to some situations where the comma may be omitted (and what qualifies as "very short and closely connected" is a matter of opinion), it also qualifies its statements about the use of commas with the words *usually* and *recommendation*.

In other words, there is no absolute rule. The use of a comma in the example sentence in the question is probably more common than not—but the lack of a comma isn't actually *wrong*, unless you are following a specific style guide or other form of prescriptive grammar that says to never omit it. But, in that case, it's only wrong according to *that* particular guidance.