# When is it more correct to say 'did not' and when 'didn't'?

Tags: abbreviations, negation

I noticed multiple times, when writing in Microsoft Word that the program suggests a correction, from either form to the other.

I can't seem to follow the logic.

When is it better to say `did not`, and when is it better to say `didn't`?

---

Feel free to add or suggest relevant tags, as I am unfamiliar with the word for this subject in English.

---

EDIT:
[image]

above: Word tries to tell me what to do

Comment: Could you please provide a context where Word suggests changing **did not** into **didn’t**, and/or vice versa?

Comment: Basically, Word barely has a clue -- it's guessing.  A big part of the choice has to do with emphasis.

Comment: I'd like to quote a @Robusto comment from [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532676/comma-use-in-microsoft-word): **Word is an idiot.**

Comment: @ambitious_ph1lologist added a case from today

Comment: More correct? Something is correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in this screenshot (from my computer) that Microsoft Word lists contractions in its grammar settings under "Style":

[image]

This is because using contractions in formal writing is generally frowned upon, unless they are used for a very specific purpose (e.g. quoting someone). The reason why Microsoft Word may suggest correcting contractions is simply to make your writing more formal.

In terms of when you should use *did not* as opposed to *didn't*, I think it depends on the situation, and on your relationship with the intended audience. If you're writing a dissertation or a report to your boss, maybe use *did not*; if you're writing a text or email to your friend, I'm sure *didn't* would be just fine.

Comment: I would take that answer, if there weren't times where it suggested the opposite. I will wait until the next time it does that and upload that as well.

Comment: Please see an edit OP made to his post. It seems that contractions in this particular case are not related to formal/informal style as there is contraction which is not underlined.

Comment: However, in general I agree with your statement about using contractions in formal/informal styles, and OP asked “when is it better...” Answer seems legit.

Comment: @Gulzar You'll have to explain where you see contradictions. I think I made the distinction between formal and informal writing quite clear.

Comment: @ambitious_ph1lologist Thanks for the heads up. I don't know how I'm going to be able to edit my answer. Maybe Word detects "weren't" and not "didn't" but I'm not sure. I'm not a Word expert. I think however, regardless of the particular contraction, the logic in my answer still applies.