# Punctuation, compound sentence, Oxford, and

Tags: punctuation

I've got myself confused with comma placement before the word 'and'.

I've read elsewhere on here that a comma should go before the word 'and' for compound sentences (this example was used, which I've borrowed, hope that's okay):

A cat can climb trees, and it can climb curtains.

[A cat can climb trees] + [A cat can climb curtains].

But how does this differ from a 'list', evoking the Oxford comma debate probably about using a comma in a list form, e.g.: a cat can climb trees, curtains and humans.  Why is the above feline example not also considered a 'list'.

Here's another example - is this a compound sentence or a list or both? I assume it's a compound sentence, but it could be considered to be listing actions that they intend to do.

EXAMPLE 
We’re risk assessing every person on a case by case basis and we’re deciding what further treatment is required.

Have I got myself unnecessarily confused?!

Comment: You start with the intent, then reduce it to writing. Going the other way is a bit of a detective’s game.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma before "and" in compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and). Getting _yourself_ confused? See ect's answer: some 'authorities' say a comma is required before a coordinator, while other (better) ones say that that's a useful rule of thumb, and experienced Anglophones are free to choose. _Would you like a pause in the read-aloud version there, or a smooth flow?_ Either works with your example.

Comment: @Frecklepaw, would you please explain why you're comparing a list of things (which I would normally understand to contain three or more things in this context) with two complete sentences separated by "and"?

Comment: Independent clauses in a compound sentence constitute primarily a compound sentence; forget any temptation to see the coordinated clauses as a list.

Answer (score 1):

You use ",and" in compound sentences *(Although this is not necessary for less wordy compound sentences*). A compound sentence is composed of two independent clauses. An independent clause is generally composed of "subject + verb + object".

When you are listing something, you generally have one subject, one verb and multiple objects. Since the object does not count as an independent clause, it does not necessitate a ",and".

E.g. 
"A cat can climb trees, and it can climb curtains."

A cat **[subject]** can climb **[verb]** trees **[object]** ***{Independent clause}***, and it **[subject]** can climb **[verb]** curtains **[object]** ***{Independent clause}*** = There are two independent clauses here.

However, if the sentence reads: "A cat can climb trees, curtains and people."

A cat **[subject]** can climb **[verb]** trees **[object]**, curtains **[object]** and people **[object]**.

There is only one subject and one verb; therefore only one independent clause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, Christina. This has all been covered here in previous threads. But 'You use ",and" in compound sentences.' sounds like it's an unbreakable law of English. But while prescriptivists/traditionalists may still say it is, many expert writers, linguists ... say it's not. Therefore it's not (there is no absolute authority). See eg [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-comma-punctuation-1689871): ' sentence contains two independent clauses... joined with[, and].... If the two independent clauses are short, however, you can usually omit the comma: _Jimmy rode his bike and Jill walked._'

Comment: I understand that, but wasn't the main intent of the question asking why we use ",and" in compound sentences and not in lists? Perhaps I should clarify that in my comment then.

Comment: It doesn't matter where in an answer we make an inaccurate statement, it still needs correcting.

Comment: I do appreciate that, which is why I modified my answer soon after you had pointed it out to me.