# Suspicious comma suggested by comma grammar checking software

Tags: commas

I was using a grammar correction software to review an article. The software suggests to insert a comma in the following text:

> In each part, the warping function creates feature maps of the input
> data and the wavelet filters extract higher frequency information from
> the input and propagate it forward.

The comma is suggested between *and* and *data* in *data and the wavelet*. I was not sure why it is suggested, if it is a correct one, and what type of comma it is.

Comment: Like with most cases of _to insert or not to insert the comma_, the use of comma here is optional. A comma signifies a pause— that's all. It won't drastically change the meaning of your sentence, whether you retain it or omit it.

Comment: It's a compound sentence, so some writers might put a comma before the conjunction.. "The wavelet filters" is the subject of another independent clause. It might be better as 2 seperate sentences...

Comment: @Cascabel— Were the two clauses separated by a comma only, that would have amounted to a solecism (comma splice). But it's perfectly alright to separate the clauses of a compound sentence with a conjunction, rendering the comma redundant at best.

Comment: I didn't say "a comma  only"...I said a comma before the "and". @user405662  I also said it was optional. See: [Comma before "and"  in compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences)

Comment: @Cascabel—Sorry, caught my eye now.

Comment: No problem...I just woke up myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the software. The comma helps you avoid a ["garden path"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) parse of the sentence.

As written, you'll start parsing the main clause as

> the warping function creates feature maps of the input data and the wavelet filters

so it seems like "wavelet filters" are also included in the feature maps. Then you encounter the verb "extract", which doesn't fit this parse, so you have to backtrack to realize that "the wavelet filters" is the subject of a new independent clause.

Inserting a comma before "and" makes it clear that this is not a list of the contents of the feature maps.