# Comma before 'and' coordinating two independent clauses

Tags: commas, rules

*Add chopped potatoes, mushrooms, and herbs, and cook for 20 minutes.*

Is a comma necessary before the second "and"? And if it is necessary, why? Please help find a grammar rule for this case.

Comment: Commas are not determined by grammar, but by intonation. Say it out loud; do you hear an intonation curve there? If so, put a comma to mark it; if not, no comma.

Comment: Since you've got a compound sentence (albeit imperative, so you don't "see" the subject), this may be helpful: [Comma before "and" in compound sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

A comma *is* necessary before the second "and". This is because it is being used as a conjunction to join two independent clauses ("Add chopped potatoes, mushrooms, and herbs", and "Cook for 20 minutes") into a single [compound sentence](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/compound-sentence/). When ["and" is used in this way](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conjunctions/), we must mark the separation between clauses with a comma.

To help illuminate the discussion, some further relevant context is that a comma *is not* necessary before the **first** "and," because this is the optional comma placement known as the "[Oxford comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/)" -- it is highly controversial in terms of *taste* (i.e. you'll very rarely find one other who both chooses to use the Oxford comma in some cases, yet omits it in others) but in terms of *correctness*, both ways are traditionally accepted in most contexts and according to most official styles.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with you. Consider this attested example "It was a perfect day and everyone was in good spirits". Here, we have a coordination of two main clauses, but no comma.

Comment: Oxford commas have already been discussed in great depth on ELU, Dan. // So has the acceptability of dropping the traditional comma before a coordinator (and BillJ gives an obviously acceptable commaless example above). Another: 'Go home and get some sleep'. The comma is totally optional; the author can indicate how they want the sentence to be read, with or without a pause. // Here, though, the fact that there is an 'and' between the last two list elements means that omitting the pre–clause-coordinator comma invites confusion; it is needed.