# Correct amendment to the following sentences, to remove multiple "AND"s

Tags: grammar

Im reading the following two sentances. I feel that the second **AND** in both of the sentances should be removed, but im not sure gramaticly how to do it correctly.

a) am i correct in my thought that the second **AND** is not correct.

b) if so would you change the sentances to remove the second **AND**

> Part of the brief was to create easy open plan spaces that weren’t clinical and cold, **AND** worked with a modern lifestyle.

> Key to the success of the project was to create a house that felt easy and relaxed **AND** where none of the aesthetics felt forced.

Comment: [Am I correct in thinking....]. This is basically editing.

Comment: which worked with////and just remove the second and in the second

Comment: "weren't clinical or cold", unless you're happy with a place that is clinical but warm. ("And" follows fine then.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You can avoid the arguable garden-path effect here ( ... that weren't A and B and C) simply by adding a second 'that' (though the comma is arguably sufficient):

- Part of the brief was to create easy open plan spaces that weren’t clinical and cold, and that worked with a modern lifestyle.

(2) Here, the addition of a comma is certainly sufficient to show that the second 'and' is 'higher-level':

- Key to the success of the project was to create a house that felt easy and relaxed, and where none of the aesthetics felt forced.

The effect is to 'promote' the second 'and' to an obvious relative-clause-coordinator. Some might like

- Key to the success of the project was to create a house that felt easy & relaxed, and where none of the aesthetics felt forced.

But this is messy and better reserved for complex lists.

[References covering the disambiguation of different coordination levels of 'and' in various sentences, other than in lists, potentially extremely difficult to find.]

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Ashworth , whats your thoughts on using a comma in front of an "and". Personally i feel its a useful piece of grammar, but i was always taught (school in the UK) that a comma before an and is not grammatically correct.

Comment: See ect's answer, sam (particularly the 'Grammartips' recommendation) and the comment where I've reinstated (and augmented) T.E.D.'s answer at [Comma before 'and' in compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences).