# does this comma belong?

Tags: commas

Sentence in question: "Please call xxx-xxx-xxxx, and let them know you are with X organization." Is the comma after the phone number necessary/required?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma before "and" in compound sentences ... necessary or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences-necessary-or-not) In this example, the comma is acceptable but not mandated. How would you elect to read the sentence? With long first independent clauses, the comma becomes like a welcome bench on a long walk.